# Разработка frontend подобно twitter, вконтакте

Tags: twitter, javascript, вконтакте

Хотелось бы понять, как устроены такие проекты. Поковырявшись в их внутренностях я обнаружил, что при переходе на новую страницу происходит запрос на сервер который возвращает либо шаблон и данные, либо шаблон, данные и уже отрендереную страницу. Но с другой стороны когда мы открываем страницу впервые, нам возвращают уже готовый хтмл, а далее все работает по схеме описанный выше, то есть без перезагрузки страницы. Я полагаю что им приходится дублировать данные, то есть отдача готового html и отдача данных с шаблонами. Как архитектурно решается эта задача

Comment: скорее всего mvc принцип (Model View Controller). Я думаю им особо не важно давать данные напрямую через Ajax, или отдавать во View чтобы та создала html

Answer (score 1):

Для каркаса такого приложения как ВК Вам вполне подойдёт http://backbonejs.ru/